# Re-create MNIST Dataset in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am newbie in Pytorch and in spite of quite a search, I am unable to grasp some concepts on datasets.
Say I retrieve the MNIST dataset as follows

```
import torch
import torchvision
data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        torchvision.datasets.MNIST("/Users/Myself/PyTorch_tutorials",
               transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
               download=True),
        batch_size=128,
        shuffle=True)
```

took me a while to understand a `DataLoader` object is an iterable, so I can check the shape of one training batch with

`next(iter(data))[0].shape`

returning

`torch.Size([128, 1, 28, 28])`

So I gather 128 is the number of training rows (as per `batch` variable, 28*28 are pixels, and the second dimension is the label.

I also saw that the dataset is organised in such way that one could iterate like

```
for (x,y) in data:
   `    do something
```

but, **FIRST QUESTION** I cannot figure out where the (x,y) tuple is defined, so training data and labels, given that

`next(iter(data))[0].shape`

returns what seems a single tensor, of shape (128,1,28,28).
How does `Dataloader` know that the second dimension in that tensor is a label? And what if it were multi-dimensional?

Now to main difficulty. say for learning purposes I would like to recreate the same dataset from scratch, from a numpy array.
I downloaded a .csv file with 59999 rows and 795 columns, the first containing the labels (column name "5"), the remaining the pixel values.
I am not interested in labels for now, just the pixel values (the dataset is to be fed to an autoencoder such as[this one](https://avandekleut.github.io/vae/)

I tried this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("mnist_train.csv")
labels = data["5"].values
datapoints = data.iloc[:,1:]
```

And then I tried

```
batch_size = 128
dataset_pytor = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(datapoints.values.reshape(-1,28,28)).unsqueeze(1))
my_loader = DataLoader(dataset_pytor, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
```

but it does not work,
I get an error in the code I am using later, which boils down to this error

```
for x in my_loader:
    
    x = x.to(device)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to'
```

I cannot understand what is going on. If I run

```
for x in my_loader:
    print(type(x))
```

I get type lists.

If I run the same but for  `data` , so the DataLoader defined above using the in-built MNIST dataset

```
for x in my_data:
    print(type(x))
```

I also get lists. Only if I do

```
for x,y in my_data:
    print(type(x))
```

then I get

`class 'torch.Tensor'`

Why is this?
My question is then, how to recreate the MNIST dataset from a numpy array?

Comment: `next(iter(data))` is a tuple with two elements. You are already accessing the first element with `next(iter(data))[0]`. The second dimension in `torch.Size([128, 1, 28, 28])` is the number of channels (1 = greyscale, 3 = RGB/color).

Comment: @Plagon, I see, missed that, silly me.And i see the point about the tuple, yes i used tge subscript [0] as I was trying to understand, so the first element of the typle is thectraining batch, the second the labela. But then, as I created my dataset from the numpy array without labels, why do i get a list, when itersting over my_loader instead of a pytorch tensor? Thanks fot yout patience

Comment: The [TensorDataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataset.html#TensorDataset) just iterates over an iterable. The type hint (`torch.tensor`) tells you that it expects a tensor. You can see in the code, that it does not check the type nor does it attempt to convert any thing to a tensor. Thats why you will get a list out.

Answer (score 0):

To comprehensively answer all your questions:
128,1,28,18 is the shape of your tensor, where 128 is the batch size, 1 is the dimension ( RGB will be 3 here ) and the 2 28’s are, as you rightly put it, the shape of the image.
So, your first question is answered above – there is no issue where the dataloader takes the second dimension as the label.
As to your second question, after you convert the csv file into a TensorDataset object, if you iterate through it, you get a tuple. The first element of each tuple is your tensor.

```
  for x in dataset_pytor:
        print(x[0].shape)
        break
```

Try the above code with your dataset_pytor object

An easy way to recreate MNIST is to create your own dataset object:

**I am assuming my first column in the dataframe contains my labels**

```
  from torch.utils.data import Dataset

  class MNIST(Dataset):
     def __init__(self,dataframe,transform=False):
         self.dataframe = dataframe
         self.transform = transform
         self.sample = self.dataframe.iloc[:,1:]
         self.label = self.dataframe["label"]
     def __len__(self):
         return len(self.label)

     def __getitem__(self,index):
    
    
         img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(self.dataframe.iloc[index,1:].values.reshape(-1,28,28))
         label_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.array(self.label[index]))
         return img_tensor,label_tensor
```

Your dataframe will be given as an input to create the above class.

```
  trainset = MNIST(data)
  #data is your dataframe
  my_loader = DataLoader(trainset, shuffle=True, batch_size=128)
```